# Python - Selecting All Row Values That Meet A particular Criteria Once

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, deduplication

I have a form set up with the following fields: Date Time, ID, and Address. This form auto assigns each entry a unique id string (U_ID) and then this data is later output to a csv with headers and rows something like this:

```
Date Time       ID    U_ID     Address
9/12/13 12:07   13    adfasd   1345 Wilson Way
9/12/13 13:45   8     jklj     1456 Jackson Hollow
9/13/13 14:55   13    klidh    1345 Wilson Way
9/13/13 15:00   8     ikodl    1456 Jackson Hollow
```

I am looking for a way to remove duplicate submissions by those with the same ID via Python Script, while maintaining the rest of the data in the row. Ideally I want to keep only the first entry associated with the ID in the csv file.

The output should look something like this:

```
Date Time       ID    U_ID     Address
9/12/13 12:07   13    adfasd   1345 Wilson Way
9/12/13 13:45   8     jklj     1456 Jackson Hollow
```

So far I'm stuck at:

```
import csv

with open('/Users/user/Desktop/test.csv', 'rb') as f:
r = csv.reader(f)
headers = r.next()
rows = [(Date Time, ID, U_ID, Address) for Date Time, ID, U_ID, Address in r]
clean = [row for row in rows if row[1] != '#N/A']
clean2 = list(set(row[1]))
```

This gives me a list with only the unique values for ID, but I'm not sure how to recover all of the other data associated with the rows for those values.

As stated if I can get the earliest submission as well, that would be wonderful, but honestly any unique submission by ID should do.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html), this is how you would do it:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_table('test.csv')\
  .drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'])\
  .to_csv('output.csv', index=None, sep='\t')
```

**output.csv**:

```
Date    Time    ID  U_ID    Address
9/12/13 12:07   13  adfasd  1345 Wilson Way
9/12/13 13:45   8   jklj    1456 Jackson Hollow
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks Elyase!

Answer (score 0):

First off, the file above is a fixed-width file, not a csv. Use fixed-width string indexing.

The easiest way to do what you want is to store the unique parts in a set, which lets you quickly check if they've already been seen before.

```
path = '/Users/user/Desktop/test.csv'
already_read = set()
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    header = f.readline().strip()
    print header
    for line in f:
        unique_part = line[17:].strip()
        if unique_part in already_read:
            continue
        already_read.add(unique_part)
        print line.strip()
```

If the file is a TSV (tab-separated file), you can use `split` instead of raw indexing:

```
path = '/Users/user/Desktop/test.csv'
already_read = set()
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    header = f.readline().strip()
    print header
    for line in f:
        unique_part = '\t'.join(line.strip().split('\t')[2:])
        if unique_part in already_read:
            continue
        already_read.add(unique_part)
        print line.strip()
```